# Looking to name pdf files with a string different to bibkey

Tags: pdf, bibtex, org-ref

I recently started to incorporate Emacs as part of my workflow. Specifically, I am looking forward to a system that allows me to maintain and manage my bibliography. For this purpose I am now using `org-ref` with `ivy` as the completion system. Coming from using Zotero, I like having short bibkeys (eg. `Author2021`) as in this format it is easier to the eye in latex documents. On the other hand, I like my pdf files named with a more descriptive text such as `Author 2021 - The title of the publication.pdf` as I systematically find myself looking for files through the OS.

I have been able to accomplish the former (short bibkeys) by defining a function to be run when the system calls `bibtex-generate-autokey`. For example, when I call `org-ref-clean-bibtex-entry`. However, I haven't been able to even look at the right place in the documentation to have a different pdf naming convention.

Any help towards this dual goal is greatly appreciated as my understanding and experience with `lisp` is very limited.

Comment: How are you generating your .bib entries?

Comment: I am using `org-ref` for this. Like adding through arxiv identifiers, DOIs, or weblinks.

Comment: The Emacs tools (org-ref, helm-bibtex, ivy-bibtex) I'm familiar with assume your pdfs are named to match the bib key. I don't know a straightforward way to support short bib keys and long pdf file names at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best way to do this would be along these lines:

1. Write a function that takes a bibtex key and generates the pdf filename you want, e.g. it looks up the bibtex entry, gets the authors, year and title, and constructs a legitimate filename from them. There might be lots of corner cases to deal with latex markup in author names and titles. I think this function should return the full path to where the file will be.
2. Set the value of `org-ref-get-pdf-filename-function` to the name of the function in 1.

I think that will cause newly added pdf files to have the name you want.

Comment: Easiest (and most reliable) would be to just grab the BibTeX name for the entry: They can't contain funky characters, and must be unique (at least in your *.bib file(s)). Easy to extract from the entry, as a bonus.

Comment: Thanks a lot @john-kitchin. I'll try to implement what you suggest. I might take a while for me to set it up. I'll make an update here as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

It is been a while, but I finally found the `bibtex-completion-pdf-field` variable in the documentation. My problem was sorted out easily with

```
(setq bibtex-completion-pdf-field "file")
```

in my config file. I am just leaving this for the sake of completion.